# Decrypting a PDF with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, encryption, passwords

I have a NodeJS script, that reads PDFs, I was wondering how one can go about decrypting a PDF with a supplied password with NodeJS specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-qpdf npm module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf)
Simple example code found in the documentation of node-qpdf module is:
To encrypt a pdf

```
var qpdf = require('node-qpdf');

var options = {
    keyLength: 128,
    password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD_TO_ENCRYPT',
    restrictions: {
        print: 'low',
        useAes: 'y'
    }
}

qpdf.encrypt(localFilePath, options, outputFilePath);
```

To decrypt the pdf

```
var qpdf = require('node-qpdf');

qpdf.decrypt(localFilePath, 'YOUR_PASSWORD_TO_DECRYPT_PDF', outputFilePath);
```

Comment: This requires qpdf to be installed on your OS?, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have this dependency.

Comment: @altus installation can be done specific to that project only, not required to install on the OS.

Answer (score -2):

I also try to decrpt password protected pdf using below function but don't know how to get base64 data or file

```js
const qpdf = require('node-qpdf');
await qpdf.decrypt('lic_demo.pdf', 'awxpt1377q12081992', 'demo.pdf');
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32237936)

Comment: Dileep gave [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620598/19068) with more detail, two years earlier.